# window management: draw new gui window on top of terminal pane that launched it

Tags: linux, window-manager, i3-window-manager

fyi, I use the i3 window manager.

One of the primary reason I prefer terminal based applications is that they use the same window pane as the shell I launched them from. I exit the program, and I am right back in my shell, with my environment, workdir, and all shell goodness still there.

When I open a gui program from the shell on the other hand, it spawns a new window pane, which I usually just tab with the parent shell. I may want that behavior sometimes, but not usually because it's just one more pane to cycle through. Dmenu is one solution to this problem, but then I lose my environment, workdir, and shell goodness.

If I could somehow tell my GUI application to draw its window on top of my terminal window, I wouldn't even need the likes of dmenu. Dmenu seems pretty redundant when we have shells...

Any suggestions? Perhaps someone who has hacked around with i3? I'm open to editing the source.

Answer (score 0):

After discovering the i3 scratchpad, xdotool and the wait command, I came up with this somewhat hacky script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash 

"$*" &                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 child="$!"                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 xdotool set_window --name "$!" `xdotool getactivewindow`                                                                                                                                                           
 i3-msg move scratchpad                                                                                                                                                                                           
 wait $child                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 i3-msg [title="$child"] scratchpad show                                                                                                                                                                            
 i3-msg floating toggle

usage: launch-hide <my-gui-program>
```

So, I name the parent shell window the pid of the gui child, send it off to the scratchpad, then, when I exit the child process, launch-hide is woken up, where it then grabs the window from the scratchpad with the corresponding child pid.

Add autocompletion:

```
complete -F _command launch-hide
```